# How to automate Lightswitch for metaprogramming

Tags: code-generation, metaprogramming, dsl, visual-studio-lightswitch

I really like the Ria Services approach, and I see Lightswitch as the next higher level of abstraction, but my scenario is this:

I need to be able to define a Lighswitch app without having to rely on the designer and tedious click-throughs. If I have access to the API that the designer uses, then I can automate application generation, I can parameterize it and apply custome logic for generating custom variations of the same application type,  I can even wrap it within a DSL. As a programmer, I want to levarge Lightswitch for developing applications by meta-programming.

I'm a programmer. Whilest I can use  the "Write Code" dropdown to insert code blocks into the Application, ApplicationDataService, EntityObject and ScreenObject classes, I would like the ability to define entites, screens, relationships and queries through code / markup / a DSL.

Obviously Lightswitch meta-programs this when I use the designer, but I would like to do it myself. What I would like to accomplish is to create a lightswitch app - without having to click through a tool or designer. In Lightswitch, the pieces are obviously there (the designer leverages them), but they are not exposed as a public API. being a plugin for visual studio, perhaps there is a VSIX API extension I can leverage for automating Lightswitch? Show me some code.

Answer (score 0):

The LS team have not yet released any official API information. As you may know however, all of various data/query/screen definitions exist in the ApplicationDefinition.lsml file, located in the LS project's "Data" folder.

I would hope that API information will be made available once the RTM has been released.

Yann